# Is it more efficient to serialize a Map or List of objects in java?

Tags: java, serialization

Or maybe there is no difference? The data is the same, because I need to save a Key-Value, so in case of the list I will have to implement KeyValue structure and put it into the list.

Comment: There likely is a difference but asking this question makes me wonder if you are actually trying to solve a different problem

Comment: @matt b, I have a multiple key-value entries I need to serialize in a single go and I think the easiest way is to put them into the list or a map, just wonder which one will be more efficient?

Comment: @Amber, creating a good microbenchmark can be tricky, would rather to know what is actually going on.

Comment: I would suggest serializing your data however it is used. If it's used as a List, serialize the List, if it's used as a Map of key-value entries, serialize the Map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a more efficient serialization, I suggest you use a different serialization like hessian.

Comment: Or use `Externalizable` to manually tweak the serialization/deserialization process.

Answer (score 3):

I would think it's less work to serialize a list, since they have less to keep track of than a map, but I wouldn't worry about it. If you need to use a map in your program, use a map, and serialize whatever data structure you're using to store your data. You shouldn't choose your data structure based on ease of serialization, it's going to be negligible

Answer (score 2):

Efficiency is the same.  Except that a map holds keys and data, so it has twice the data to serialize.

But the big oh (`O(n)`) stays the same.  Use whatever data structure fits best in your application because the difference wont matter in the long run.